# strange error 'npm WARN express-validation@1.0.2 requires a peer of joi@* but none is installed...?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

What does '`npm WARN express-validation@1.0.2 requires a peer of joi@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`' mean? And how can I solve it?

---

when i run:

```
npm install express-validation --save
```

I get:

```
npm WARN express-validation@1.0.2 requires a peer of joi@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

so then i run:

```
npm install -g npm-install-peers
```

then:

```
npm-install-peers
```

then I get:

```
This package doesn't seem to have any peerDependencies
```

so then i run:

```
npm install express-validation --save
```

I get:

```
npm WARN express-validation@1.0.2 requires a peer of joi@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it yourself with `npm install joi --save`

Answer (score 0):

The package name is wrong. If you are trying to validate data in your app you should consider start looking for express-validator.

Express-validation requires a peer of joy and i dont know what both means.